# PHP exec 'VBoxManage startvm'

Tags: php, html, debian, virtualbox

I'm trying to start virtualbox machine throught PHP script on server. I wrote this script:

```
<?php
    echo(exec("sudo VBoxManage startvm 'EnterToJa'"));
?>
```

And it runs on server, but it waits only for first line:

```
Waiting for VM "EnterToJa" to power on...
```

After that it probably kills it. When I run that VBoxManage command on my server from terminal it works, but I have to wait ~5 seconds and I this that is the problem.

P.S.
www-data <- has got permission to run sudo without password

Comment: "www-data <- has got permission to run sudo without password" - Impressive. Can you give us the address to have a try ourselves?

Comment: hahaha I know that is stupid, but at this moment I'm just testing it why it is not working. As soon as this will work, www-data will lost this permissions.

Comment: Do not do this. Period. About your goal: make a server based script that holds the command instead and execute that. This way you at least have limited that down. _And_ you can test it without having to expose everything on a web server.

Comment: I wrote simple sh script, but still it only output "Waiting for VM "EnterToJa" to power on..." and that is all. It doesn't wait for "VM "EnterToJa" has been successfully started."

Comment: You _do_ know that `exec` only returns the first line of output? You _did_ read its documentation? So you _do_ know how to get the full output?

Comment: I know that and I tried "exec("sudo VBoxManage startvm 'EnterToJa'",$zmienna1,$zmienna2)", but it only return first line anyway.

Comment: Yes, why should it return more than the first line? The function _always_ only returns the first line.

Comment: Ok, so I will use "exec("sudo VBoxManage startvm 'EnterToJa'")", because I don't care about output. I would like to start Virtual Machine, but I can't.

Comment: Can anyone solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your VirtualBox work you have to add into your command line `|at now`.

Example:

```
<?php
    exec("sudo VBoxManage startvm 'EnterToJak' --type HeadLess|at now");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Running this command in background should help in your case.

This should help:

```
   exec("sudo VBoxManage startvm 'EnterToJa' &");
```